# row border-top border-bottom hover single line?

Tags: html, css

First, im new so dont give me a hard time ;)

i have a problem with styling my foreach. What I want is that if I hover on the row. It only returns single line bottom and top border. 
In this case when I hover on the next row the bottom top border from other rows are there creating a 2px border. I tried many things margin-top:-1px etc... some gave me a better result but not the final one.

[image]

[image]

```
.frameregels{
border-bottom:1px solid #e1e1e1;
border-top:1px solid #e1e1e1;       
}
.frameregels:nth-child(odd){
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
.frameregels:nth-child(even){
background-color:#f9f9f9;       
}
.frameregels:hover{
background-color:#ecf5f9;
border-color:#66afe9;
}

<div class="xxlarge-12 xlarge-12 large-12 medium-12 small-12 columns frameregels">
<div class="xxlarge-1 xlarge-1 large-2 columns large-down-hidden">[artikelnr]</div>
<div class="xxlarge-11 xlarge-11 large-10 columns large-down-hidden">[omschrijving]</div>
</div>
<div class="xxlarge-12 xlarge-12 large-12 medium-12 small-12 columns frameregels">
<div class="xxlarge-1 xlarge-1 large-2 columns large-down-hidden">[artikelnr]</div>
<div class="xxlarge-11 xlarge-11 large-10 columns large-down-hidden">[omschrijving]</div>
</div>
<div class="xxlarge-12 xlarge-12 large-12 medium-12 small-12 columns frameregels">
<div class="xxlarge-1 xlarge-1 large-2 columns large-down-hidden">[artikelnr]</div>
<div class="xxlarge-11 xlarge-11 large-10 columns large-down-hidden">[omschrijving]</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you've fallen into the same trap that all new askers fall into: you didn't read the Stack Overflow help docs. Those docs make it clear that you should include your code so that people can volunteer their valuable time to help you.

Comment: Check your CSS for something like `.tableRow:hover` or `tr:hover` - It's likely that it's just the styling on your table rows.

Comment: Was not clear about it. its divs not table

Comment: Make sure to tag your queston appropriately - if it's a php question, add a php tag (and you probably want to post your php code). Also, noone is given a hard time, unless they fail to read the help docs, in which case the feeling is mutual, as all you're doing is giving *us* a hard time.

Comment: its not a php question if it was I will be using the php tag.. and as commented above I included the css code that is in charge of handeling the basic and hover.

Comment: My bad, however in this case you need to remove the PHP from the title altogether - as you can see, it's confusing ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`margin-bottom:-1px` is the completely right idea, however you need a few more things for that to work:

- make sure you don't apply it to the last element to retain a clean bounding box of your list
- position the elements in a way that accepts a `z-index` property so that you can shift the element you're hovering in the foreground. If you don't do this, you will change the color of your border, but the next element's border is just going to overlay it.

In practice, this is how it works (padding added for beauty):

```css
.frameregels {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  border-top: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
.frameregels:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
.frameregels:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.frameregels:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
.frameregels:hover {
  background-color: #ecf5f9;
  border-color: #66afe9;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="frameregels">
  <div>[artikelnr]</div>
  <div>[omschrijving]</div>
</div>
<div class="frameregels">
  <div>[artikelnr]</div>
  <div>[omschrijving]</div>
</div>
<div class="frameregels">
  <div>[artikelnr]</div>
  <div>[omschrijving]</div>
</div>
<div class="frameregels">
  <div>[artikelnr]</div>
  <div>[omschrijving]</div>
</div>
```